# for loop file data is repeating and skipping other lines c++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, file-io, getline

I'm almost done with my program that reads in contact data, except when I read it in, certain lines repeat and skip other lines. For example, this is what happens currently:

```
Name: Herb  SysAdmin
Address: 27 Technology Drive
Age: 27 Technology Drive
Phone: 25
Type: WORK
```

It repeats address, but skips phone. Code below.

```
int EnterContact(string contacts, ListofContacts list)
    // first number from the file depicting
{
    // constant
    ifstream inFile;            //input file stream object
    inFile.open("contacts.txt");

    // variables
    std:: string name,
        address,
        phone,
        contactType;
    string line;
    int age;

    int conNum = 0;
    inFile >> conNum;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "There are " << conNum << " contacts in this phone." << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < conNum; x++)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        getline(inFile, name);
        getline(inFile, address);
        inFile >> age >> phone >> contactType;
        list[x] = Contact(name, address, age, phone, GetType(contactType));
    }

    //close the file
    inFile.close();

    return conNum;
}
```

any ideas or if i'm just missing a line of code it'd be greatly appreciated.

my input file looks like this:

```
3
Herb SysAdmin
27 Technology Drive
25
850-555-1212
WORK
Sally Sallster
48 Friendly Street
22
850-555-8484
FRIEND
Brother Bob
191 Apple Mountain Road
30
850-555-2222
RELATIVE
```

Comment: What do your input files look like?

Comment: Hold on, I have no idea how to format on comments

Comment: i included my input file now

Comment: My guess is that you're having a problem with the code that prints the contents of the `Contact` object. I'm not sure how else to explain the fact that the age is printing out as a string, when it's clearly an `int` in your code.

Comment: What are you using to print out that output?  Also what is the code for constructor of `Contact`?

Comment: `        getline(inFile, line);
        getline(inFile, name);
        getline(inFile, address);
        inFile >> age >> phone >> contactType;
        std::cout<<name<<std::endl
                <<address<<std::endl
                <<age<<std::endl
                <<phone<<std::endl
                <<contactType<<std::endl;`

prints proper information what does the constructor for contact look like and what does your print function look like

Comment: Basically what that monstrosity does is prints the information out right as you are reading it in. it prints out correct information so the problem must be ineither the print function or the constructor of your contact class

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < conNum; x++)
{
    getline(inFile, line);
    getline(inFile, name);
    getline(inFile, address);
    inFile >> age >> phone >> contactType;
    list[x] = Contact(name, address, age, phone, GetType(contactType));
}
```

is wrong because you're mixing formatted input with unformatted input without clearing the newline left after the extraction into `conNum` and subsequently into `contactType`.

To fix it, use `std::ws`:

```
getline(inFile >> std::ws, line);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```